# Get posts data from any other website onto our website dynamically

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

Hey there I am new in codeigniter i want to get posts title and featured image from any websites running on WordPress into my website based on codeigniter so post title and image will be show onto my site and whenver user click on that image he/she must redirect to original site to where original post is held

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then u need write `Grabber` script for this feature.